# Why is that everytime I logout and then logged in again the pk becomes none in django

Tags: python, django

I always get this error:

Reverse for 'user_home' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'pk': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['ibs/(?P[0-9]+)/home/$']

in my template I can display my user.pk (it is equal to 1) but when i use it and pass it in my views i got the error above (pk: none). I have read some threads about this. Some are because of the url patterns but I changed and check my urls but nothing happened. Still gets the error.

this is my url:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ibs/$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^ibs/register/$', views.user_add, name='user_add'),
    url(r'^ibs/login/$', views.user_login, name='user_login'),
    url(r'^ibs/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/home/$', views.user_home,      name='user_home'),
    url(r'^ibs/(?P<user_pk>[0-9]+)/logout/$', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^ibs/(?P<pk_item_add>[0-9]+)/additem/$', views.item_add, name='item_add'),
    url(r'^ibs/(?P<pk_item>[0-9]+)/viewitem/(?P<pk_user>[0-9]+)/$', views.item_detail, name='item_detail'),
]
```

my template:

```
{% block home %}
<li class="active"><a href="{% url "user_home" pk=user.pk %}">Home</a></li>
{% endblock home %}

{% block register %}
{% endblock register %}

{% block login %}
{% endblock login %}

{% block logout %}
<li>
    <a method="post" href="{% url "user_logout" user_pk=user.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout
</a>
</li>
{% endblock logout %}


{% block post %}
<li>
    <a method="post" href="{% url "item_add" pk_item_add=user.pk %}"> {{user.pk}}
</a>
</li>
{% endblock post %}

def user_login(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    #username is unique, get User where username is equal to requested username
    username = User.objects.get(username = request.POST['username'])

    if username.password == request.POST['password']:
        request.session['username'] = username.id
        return redirect('system.views.user_home', pk=username.id)
else:

return render(request, 'system/user_login.html')
```

views.py

```
def user_home(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
    try:
        if request.session['username'] == user.pk:
            items = Item.objects.all()
            types = Type.objects.all()
            return render(request, 'system/user_home.html', {'user':user, 'types':types, 
                                                         'items': items})
        else:
            return redirect('system.views.user_login')

    except KeyError:
        return redirect('system.views.user_login')

def user_logout(request, user_pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_pk)
    try:
        del request.session['username']
        return redirect('system.views.user_login')

    except KeyError:
        pass

    return redirect('system.views.user_login')
```

Where did I go wrong? I passed all the necessary data from views to templates.

Comment: Are you using Django's auth system? I feel like a lot of what you've written here could be less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

When a user is not logged in the `user` is likely the `models.AnonymousUser` which does not have a primary key.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymous-users

If the user is not logged in then you probably don't want them to see that template at all. Redirect them to the login page in the view or check that the user is not anonymous in the template.

Comment: but the problem is, when I successfully log in again, the user.pk becomes none when I pass it from template to view.

Comment: Print out the user object in the view, is it the same as the user that is logged in? What does the view look like?

Comment: I edited my post. I put my views.py. Yes it is the same user.

Comment: What template file is that above `system/user_login.html`?

Comment: it is my system/user_home.html. When successfully logged in you can view the home. And there's an option there. If you click the "post"(an <a> tag) it will pass {% url "item_add" pk_item_add=user.pk %} and there I got an error reverse match keyword arguments '{u'pk': None}
Here's the error came from:

% block home %}

      <li class="active"><a href="
      {% url "user_home" pk=user.pk %}
      ">Home</a></li>

      
 {% endblock home %}

Comment: the {% block post %} that is the "post"(an <a>tag) is what I mean. See the {{ user.pk }}, it displays the id of the current user. And it's correct. but still get the pk:none error.